# Conditionally invoke/prevent invocation of setter in Javascript's defineProperty object

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

Is there a way to catch a Javascript set function in defineProperty, perform some logic and then decide whether to actually allow the original set function to be invoked?

**Example**

```
var scope = {}; 
scope.myVar = 1;

scope._myVar = scope.myVar; 
Object.defineProperty(scope, "myVar", {  
  get: function(){
    return scope._myVar;
  },
  set: function(val) {
    scope._myVar = val;
    //Do some other work   
  } 
}

//Now when scope.myVar is changed, its setter is invoked 
//I would like to write some code here now that will run even before the
//myVar setter, do some work, and then decide whether to invoke the setter
//or not.  If it decides to not invoke the setter, then it will be as
//though the scope.myVar = ... was never called.

//Psuedo-code
scope._setMyVar = scope.setMyVar;
scope.setMyVar = function(val) {
  //do some work
  var condition = resultOfWorkAbove;

  if(condition) {
    scope._setMyVar(val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can get the old setter (what you've written as `scope._setMyVar = scope.setMyVar;` in your pseudocode) with [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).

```
(function(obj, prop) { // an IEFE for local variables
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop),
        oldsetter = desc.set;
    desc.set = function(val) {
        var condition = … // do some work;
        if (condition)
            oldsetter.call(this, val);
    };
    Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, desc);
}(scope, "myVar"));
```

<sub>Of course, this does only work if the original property descriptor had [`configurable` set to `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description), otherwise we cannot overwrite it.</sub>

Comment: Awesome work @Bergi.  I had no idea.  This is very pwoerful and I assume incredibly easy to aim at my own foot.  :)

Comment: Yeah, calling this on a data property (not an accessor one) will hurt for example :-)

Comment: I'm running this code on IE10 without setting configurable to true and it's running fine.  When I do a look-up on the configurable property, I see it defaults to false.  Weird.

Comment: `defineProperty` is running without throwing in sloppy mode, yes, but the new setter should not be in effect then. Or does IE10 really overwrite the setter and `// do work` is executed?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading my code and have inadvertently done something to correct that, `//do some work` is executing